# Access: Sort by Date from different source

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2016

I want to create a report. Grouped by month (from date1) there should be counted how many records match for property1 has value A, B, C, D ... and property2 1, 2 or 3.  Additionally there should be grouped by the same month (but this time from date2) property3 has value A, B, C, D ... and property2 1, 2 or 3.

I created two querys that count the amount of matching records for each combination of property1 and 2 (Property3 and 2 respective). But how can I make the result be grouped by the same month in one report?

Comment: Show sample data and desired result for a vote

Answer (score 0):

formatting the date to show month only in both queries. creating a third query, adding the first two, conecting the month-fields, add all the other counting-field, create the form based on the third query.